# Enable SSMS in SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

We just had an upgrade of all our computers here, and on one of them we loaded our licensed copy of Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2005 Developer edition.  I then loaded the service packs (4 for SS).  There is still no icon for SSMS in the Start Menu.

How do I enable SSMS in this version of SQL Server?

(OS: Windows 7 64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you search your system for SqlWb.exe or ssms.exe? If those aren't there then run setup again and make sure you choose "Workstation Components, Books Online and Development Tools."

Comment: In Windows Search, ssms.exe comes up, but errors out when it runs.  I'll look at reinstalling.